# how to get checkbox is checked when checkbox is in table rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

how to get checkbox is checked when checkbox is in table rows

```
<asp:Table ID="mytbl" runat="server">
</asp:Table>

while (res.Read())
{
    trow = new TableRow();
    tcell1 = new TableCell();
    tcell2 = new TableCell();
    CheckBox ch = new CheckBox();
    ch.CssClass = "chkBox";
    ch.ID = res.GetInt32(1) + "_" + res.GetInt32(2);
    //ch. = res.GetInt32(1) + "_" + res.GetInt32(2);
    values.Add(res.GetInt32(1) + "_" + res.GetInt32(2));
    tcell1.Controls.Add(ch);
    tcell2.Text = res.GetString(0);
    trow.Cells.Add(tcell1);
    trow.Cells.Add(tcell2);
    mytbl.Rows.Add(trow);    
}
```

I want check checkbox is checked and save result in database

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4YJvHFH.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the example below.I don't have access to your database so I changed the way I populate the table on my side just to get it working but when you click the `Save` button the logic loops through the table and let's you evaluate the checkbox(if it was checked or not):

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TableRow row1 = this.CreateRow("checkBox1", "chkBox", "Row 1");
    TableRow row2 = this.CreateRow("checkBox2", "chkBox", "Row 2");

    mytbl.Rows.Add(row1);
    mytbl.Rows.Add(row2);
}

private TableRow CreateRow(string id, string css, string text)
{
    var row = new TableRow();
    var cell1 = new TableCell();
    var cell2 = new TableCell { Text = text };
    var checkBox = new CheckBox
    {
        CssClass = css,
        ID = id
    };
    cell1.Controls.Add(checkBox);
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
    return row;
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TableRow row in mytbl.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
        string rowText = row.Cells[1].Text;

        if(checkBox.Checked)
        {
            //Perform further processing
        }
    }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<form runat="server">
    <asp:table id="mytbl" runat="server"></asp:table>
    <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood that you want to see which checkboxes are checked in the table then based on that you want to do some operation on that checked records.

So to do that you can loop and see checkboxes are checked or not.

```
HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)Page.FindControl("mytbl");
foreach (HtmlTableRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        foreach (Control c in cell.Controls)
        {
            if (c is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)c).Checked) 
            {
                //do some operation here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Have you added  `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` reference and namespace?see the error is clearing telling you what to do.

Comment: The error clearly tells you that there is no rows in table and you are trying to loop.check that your table is generated before doing so.